# How to delete the oldest record and retain the recent records using a temp table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to delete the oldest record but retain the recent records in SQL in the below given example ?

The output display and records removal is expected in a temp table without affecting the main table

Current:

```
StockId   Name   CreatedDate   Status 
1        Apple     10/09/2017     2
1        Apple     11/09/2017     2
1        Apple     12/09/2017     2
2        Orange    15/09/2017     2
2        Orange    16/09/2017     1
```

Expected:

```
StockId   Name   CreatedDate   Status 
1        Apple     12/09/2017     2
2        Orange    16/09/2017     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try Something like this:

```
WITH cte
AS
(
SELECT *,row_number() over (partition by StockId, Name order by CreatedDate desc) as row_number 
FROM yourtable
) DELETE FROM cte WHERE row_number>1
```

Comment: @jyong - please explain why this isn't suitable. Otherwise this question is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to get the newest record per stock ID into the new table, use an insert select. Use `ROWNUMBER` to rank your records.

```
insert into temp (stockid, name, createddate, status)
select stockid, name, createddate, status
from
(
  select 
    stockid, name, createddate, status,
    rownumber() over (partition by stockid order by createddate desc) as rn
  from mytable
)
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a nested query that shows the StockId and the most recent data. Then, remove all the row in the original table that aren't in the nested query:

```
/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(1, 1, 'Apple', '2017/09/10', 2);
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(2, 1, 'Apple', '2017/09/11', 2);
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(3, 1, 'Apple', '2017/09/12', 2);
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(4, 2, 'Orange', '2017/09/15', 2);
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(5, 2, 'Orange', '2017/09/16', 2);

DELETE FROM MyTable
WHERE (StockId, CreatedData) NOT IN 
                            (
                              SELECT StockId, Max(CreatedData) 
                              FROM MyTable GROUP BY StockId
                             );

/* result*/
StockId   Name   CreatedDate   Status 
 1        Apple   2017/09/12     2
 2        Orange  2017/09/16     1
```

Comment: This code will not work. You can only have one column in the IN clause's subquery. Try using EXISTS instead

Comment: I don't think that is valid tsql